# The map (item) limit has been hit, how do I fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I co run a public anarchy server.  We had a user come on, duplicate maps, and fill the maps to the limit. idcounts.dat displays -32740.  This causes all kinds of weird things when new maps are created which are all labeled map#0. I attempted to set idcounts.dat to the number of maps that were legitimate (304).  This did not work and when I set a map and rechecked idcounts.dat, it was back to the original -32740.  I am currently deleting the 32740 map dat files off of server to see what that does.

I have google searched with no luck.  Has anyone solved this problem without deleting all current maps and idcounts file?  I would like to keep the original 304 maps.

Comment: You need to do both, delete the map_xy files and reset the count in `idcounts.dat`.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I had figured it out before your reply but your reply is exactly right.  I tried to do it with the server running and the idcounts was just being over written.  I had to shut down server, modify idcounts, and delete extra maps.

Comment: @dly Please post this as answer so that it can be accepted and this question doesn't remain open.

Comment: @Someone Dly posted his comment as an answer, can you please mark it as accepted to indicate that this is the answer that solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

As already stated in my comment the map count can be reset by doing both, deleting the excess `map_xy` files *and* resetting the counter in `idcounts.dat`.